# Get to specific line in file, then start writing after that line

Tags: python, file, io

I'm writing a python script to add a method to some iOS code. I need the script to scan the the file for a specific line and then start writing to the file after that line. For example:

- script encounters this line

**#pragma mark - Method**

- then writes method after this line

How can I do that in Python?

Thanks!

Collin

Comment: Please mention regarding what have to tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you don't want to actually write over anything that comes after the `#pragma` marker, as your question implies.

```
marker = "#pragma Mark - Method\n"
method = "code to add to the file\n"

with open("C:\codefile.cpp", "r+") as codefile:
    # find the line
    line = ""
    while line != marker:
        line = codefile.readline()
    # save our position
    pos = codefile.tell()
    # read the rest of the file
    remainder = codefile.read()
    # return to the line after the #pragma
    codefile.seek(pos)
    # write the new method
    codefile.write(method)
    # write the rest of the file
    codefile.write(remainder)
```

If you do want to overwrite the rest of the text in the file, that's simpler:

```
with open("C:/codefile.cpp", "r+") as codefile:
    # find the line
    line = ""
    while line != marker:
        line = codefile.readline()
    # write the new method
    codefile.write(method)
    # erase everything after it from the file
    codefile.truncate()
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I actually came up with another solution, but this one is better as to not removing what comes after the mark. Thanks!