# want to merge specific code lines from 2 text files

Tags: python

for starters, i am actually a medical student, so i wouldn't know first thing about programming, but i found myself in desperate need for this, so pardon me for my complete ignorance about the subject.

i have 2 XML files containing text, each one contains nearly 2 million lines, the first one looks like this:

```
<TEXT>
    <Unknown1>-65535</Unknown1>
    <autoId>1</autoId>
    <autoId2>0</autoId2>
    <alias>Name2.Boast_Duel_Season01_sudden_death_1vs1</alias>
    <original>Уникальная массовая дуэль: Битва один на один до полного уничтожения в один раунд</original>
  </TEXT>
  <TEXT>
    <Unknown1>-65535</Unknown1>
    <autoId>2</autoId>
    <autoId2>0</autoId2>
    <alias>Name2.Boast_Duel_Season01_sudden_death_3vs3</alias>
    <original>Уникальная массовая дуэль: Битва трое на трое до полного уничтожения в один раунд</original>
```

and the second one looks like this:

```
<TEXT>
    <Unknown1>-65535</Unknown1>
    <autoId>1</autoId>
    <autoId2>0</autoId2>
    <alias>Name2.Boast_Duel_Season01_sudden_death_1vs1</alias>
    <replacement>Unique mass duel one on one battle to the complete destruction of one round</replacement>
  </TEXT>
  <TEXT>
    <Unknown1>-65535</Unknown1>
    <autoId>2</autoId>
    <autoId2>0</autoId2>
    <alias>Name2.Boast_Duel_Season01_sudden_death_3vs3</alias>
    <replacement>Unique mass duel Battle three against three to the complete destruction of one round</replacement>
  </TEXT>
```

and those blocks of code are repeated along the files for like half a million time, netting me the 2 million liner i told you about..

now what i need to do is merge both files to make the final product look like this:

```
<TEXT>
    <Unknown1>-65535</Unknown1>
    <autoId>1</autoId>
    <autoId2>0</autoId2>
    <alias>Name2.Boast_Duel_Season01_sudden_death_1vs1</alias>
    <original>Уникальная массовая дуэль: Битва один на один до полного уничтожения в один раунд</original>
    <replacement>Unique mass duel one on one battle to the complete destruction of one round</replacement>
  </TEXT>
  <TEXT>
    <Unknown1>-65535</Unknown1>
    <autoId>2</autoId>
    <autoId2>0</autoId2>
    <alias>Name2.Boast_Duel_Season01_sudden_death_3vs3</alias>
    <original>Уникальная массовая дуэль: Битва трое на трое до полного уничтожения в один раунд</original>
    <replacement>Unique mass duel Battle three against three to the complete destruction of one round</replacement>
  </TEXT>
```

so, Basically i want to add the "Replacement" line under each respective "original" line while the rest of the file is kept intact (it's the same in both) , doing this manually would take me like 2 weeks..and i only have 1 day to do so!
any help is appreciated, and again..sorry if i sound like a total idiot at this, cause i kind of am!
P.S: i can't even chose a proper tag! i will totally understand if i just get lashed in the answers now..this job is way to big for me!

Comment: You may find someone feeling generous enough to do this for you, but you should really make an attempt at doing this yourself, and then come to stackoverflow if you get stuck with something specific. "Write this program for me" questions aren't appropriate here. That said, there was actually a question asked earlier today that's somewhat relevant to what you're asking about. You could look at it as a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23767431/2073595

Comment: 2 weeks? That's about 285,714 replacements; over two 40-hour weeks, that's only a little faster than one replacement every ten seconds. I think you could do it faster than that. A week and a half.

Comment: @dano well,i just thought that you guys could direct me to the right direction to get this started, but after considering it, i realized i am in way over my head!
anyway, that other question only adds a fixed text after the mark, but i want to fish it out of the other file first, then add it! this should be tricky even for a veteran! let alone poor old me!

Comment: Ok, nice try at getting people onside by saying "medical student", but the data is about a `Unique mass duel Battle three against three to the complete destruction`. Sounds like you're trying to edit a game file. I can't see why this is of such "urgency" that you can't try and do it yourself.

Comment: @user3658890 I suggest you to learn some coding. I major in biology and used to thought I am not good at math, computer, like many other biologist. But now I learn it well so dont hesitate to do it. coding is not that hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truth about "where to start" is to learn basic python string manipulation. I was feeling nice and I like these sorts of problem, however, so here's a (quick and dirty) solution. The only things you'll need to change are the "original.xml" and "replacement.xml" file names. You'll also need a working python version, of course. That's up to you to figure out.

A couple caveats about my code:

- Parsing XML is a solved problem. Using regular expressions to do it is frowned upon, but it works, and when you're doing something as simple and fixed as this, it really doesn't matter.
- I made a few assumptions when building the outputted XML file (for example an indentation style of 4 spaces), but it outputs valid XML. The application you're using should play nice with it.

-

```
import re

def loadfile(filename):
    '''
    Returns a string containing all data from file
    '''
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    infile_string = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    return infile_string


def main():
    #load the files into strings
    original = loadfile("original.xml")
    replacement = loadfile("replacement.xml")

    #grab all of the "replacement" lines from the replacement file
    replacement_regex = re.compile("(<replacement>.*?</replacement>)")
    replacement_list = replacement_regex.findall(replacement)

    #grab all of the "TEXT" blocks from the original file
    original_regex = re.compile("(<TEXT>.*?</TEXT>)", re.DOTALL)
    original_list = original_regex.findall(original)


    #a string to write out to the new file
    outfile_string = ""
    to_find = "</original>" #this is the point where the replacement text is going to be appended after
    additional_len = len(to_find)
    for i in range(len(original_list)): #loop through all of the original text blocks
        #build a new string with the replacement text after the original
        build_string = ""
        build_string += original_list[i][:original_list[i].find(to_find)+additional_len]
        build_string += "\n" + " "*4
        build_string += replacement_list[i]
        build_string += "\n</TEXT>\n"
        outfile_string+=build_string


    #write the outfile string out to a file
    outfile = open("outfile.txt", 'w')
    outfile.write(outfile_string)
    outfile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Edit (reply to comment): The IndexError, list out of range error means that the regex isn't properly working (it's not finding the exactly correct amount of replacement text and grabbing each item to put it into a list). I tested what I wrote on the blurbs you provided, so there's a discrepancy between the blurbs you provided and the full-blown XML files. If there aren't the same amount of original/replacement tags or anything like that, that will break the code. Impossible for me to figure out without access to the files themselves.

Comment: @Luyi Tian well, i assure you that i am a medical student, you can shoot me up a question if you want to be sure..and yes! it's a game file (medical students play too, you know :D ), and NO, the reason why this is an urgency is kind of my own business..but thanks for taking the time to reply anyway.

Comment: You sir, are awesome! i almost gave up on the whole thing seeing that it was too much of a hassle for my non math-friendly brain! thanks a million, i will give this a shot.

Comment: @Luyi Tian i am so sorry, i didn't mean you..i meant "Lego stormtrooper" in my previous comment *i can't edit it since 5 minutes have passed*..i will also try your solution.
man this is an awesome community!, really..helping a complete stranger like this is just great :)

Answer (score 0):

here I present a straightforward way to do that (without xml parseing).

```
def parse_org(file_handle):
    for line in file_handle:
        if "<TEXT>" in line:
            record = line## start a new record if find tag <TEXT>
        elif "</TEXT>" in line:
            yield record## end a record if find tag <\TEXT>
            record = None
        elif record is not None:
            record +=line

def parse_rep(file_handle):
    for line in file_handle:
        if "<TEXT>" in line:
            record = None
        elif "</TEXT>" in line:
            yield record
            record = None
        elif "<replacement>" in line:
            record = line

if __name__ == "__main__":
    orginal_file = open("filepath/yourfile.xml")
    replacement_file = ("filepath/yourfile.xml")
    a_new_file = open("result_file","w")
    END = "NOT"
    while END =="NOT":
        try:
            org = parse_org(orginal_file).next()
            rep = parse_rep(replacement_file).next()
            new_record = org+rep+"</TEXT>\n"
            a_new_file.write(new_record)
        except StopIteration:
            END = "YES"
    a_new_file.close()
    orginal_file.close()
    replacement_file.close()
```

the code is written using python, and it uses keyword `yield`, use http://www.codecademy.com/ if you want to learn python, google `yield python` to learn how to use `yield` in python. if you would like to process such txt file in future, you should learn a script language, python may be the easiest one. If you encounter any questions you could post them on this website, but dont do nothing and just ask like "write this program for me".

Comment: well, @LuyiTian your script just creates an empty "result_file and

Comment: @Juicebox your's gives me an error at line 36,47 indexerror:list index out of range!
you guys already put up with me and my complete (and apparently unexcused :D ) lack of knowledge and i am thankful for that, so thank you for trying.

Comment: @user3658890 I just test my script in you given example, for simplicity I didn't add any format checking function, so if the format in your file is different from you example the script may not work

Comment: well, after a bit of digging around, i modified the script provided by juicebox a little and managed to create 2 scripts out of it, one the just extracts the "replacements" into a separate file, and another that re-compiles them after translation..thanks a lot guys :)